# Angular is throwing Unknown provider when injecting factory into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, orm, model, lodash

### **Problem:**

**Why is my Angular App throwing a Unknown Provider Error on: UnitProvider <- Unit**

### **Error:**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UnitProvider <- Unit
```

### Codepen:

### [LIVE CODE Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kCbwh)

---

I recently watched a video on Angular Youtube called:

> [Crafting the Perfect AngularJS Model and Making it Real Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHbWRFpbma4&list=UUbn1OgGei-DV7aSRo_HaAiw#t=954)
>
> **Github** [Repo](https://github.com/mattcreager/talks/tree/master/realtime-angular-model/buildr)

---

### **Background:**

I really feel inspired; I feel as if, I understand the theory and result of this approach but I'm having a lot of problems connecting all the dots.  Any extra commenting that doesnt exist would be super helpful!!!

### **Code**

js:

```
angular.module('Modelbuildr', []).config(function() {});
var app = angular.module('Modelbuildr');


// Switch COMMENT on the MainCtrls below and see it work 
//
//
//
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, Unit)           
/*app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope)*/
{
  $scope.name = "world";
  $scope.units = Unit;
  var vecA = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $scope.vecB = _.map(vecA, function(num){
      return num * 2;
    });
});

/*
  -------Resource
*/
  function Resource($http, path) {
    _.extend(this, {
      _http: $http,
      _path: path
    });
  }

  /* Factory */
  Resource.$factory =  ['$http', function($http) {
    return function(path) {
      return new Resource($http, path);
    };
  }];

  app.factory('bdResource', Resource.$factory);

  Resource.prototype.find = function(uid) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    this._http.get(this.path(uid))
      .success(deferred.resolve)
      .error(deferred.reject);

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  Resource.prototype.path = function(uid) {
    return uid ? this._path + '/' + uid : this._path;
  };

  Resource.prototype.set = function(uid, newValue) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var path = this._path + '/' + uid;

    this._http
      .put(path, newValue)
      .success(deferred.resolve)
      .error(deferred.reject);

    return deferred.promise;
  };

/*
  Resource-------
*/
/*
  -------Unit
*/
/* CONSTRUCTOR ACCEPTS PROMISE OR DATA */
  function Unit(futureUnitData) {

    /* DATA IS IMMEDIATELY AVAILABLE */
    if (!futureUnitData.inspect) {
      _.extend(this, futureUnitData);
      return;
    }

    /* THE PROMISE WILL BE UNWRAPPED FIRST */
    this.$unwrap(futureUnitData);
  }

  /* THE FACTORY WE'LL USE TO REGISTER WITH ANGULAR */
  Unit.$factory = ['$timeout', 'bdResource', function($timeout, Resource) {
    _.extend(Unit, {
      $$resource: new Resource('/units'),
      $timeout: $timeout
    });

    return Unit;
  }];

  /* ANGULAR MODULE REGISTRATION */
  angular.module('Modelbuildr').factory('bdUnit', Unit.$factory);

  /* FETCH A UNIT */
  Unit.$find = function(uid) {

    /* FALLS BACK ON AN INSTANCE OF RESOURCE */
    var futureUnitData = this.$$resource.find(uid);

    if (uid) return new Unit(futureUnitData);

    return Unit.$unwrapCollection(futureUnitData);
  };

  Unit.prototype.$unwrap = function(futureUnitData) {
    var self = this;

    this.$futureUnitData = futureUnitData;
    this.$futureUnitData.then(function(data) {
      Unit.$timeout(function() { _.extend(self, data); });
    });
  };

  Unit.$unwrapCollection = function(futureUnitData) {
    var collection = {};

    collection.$futureUnitData = futureUnitData;

    futureUnitData.then(function(units) {
      Unit.$timeout(function() {
        _.reduce(units, function(c, unit) {
          c[unit.id] = new Unit(unit);
          return c;
        }, collection);
      });
    });

    return collection;
  };

  Unit.prototype.$omit = function() {
    return _.omit(this, function(value, key){
      return _.first(key) === '$' || key === 'constructor';
    });
  };
/*
  Unit-------
*/
```

**html: **

```
<body ng-app="Modelbuildr" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Empty Angular App</h1>
  Hello {{name}}.
  Lo-dash {{vecB}}.
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `Unit` is registered into angular's module as `bdUnit`:

```
angular.module('Modelbuildr').factory('bdUnit', Unit.$factory);
```

Therefore, you should use it like this:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, bdUnit) { .. });
```

or explicitly tell angular to alias the bdUnit as Unit:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', 'bdUnit', function($scope, Unit) {
  ..
}]);
```